# Graphing Excel Data - same timeline, different amount of rows

Tags: excel, graph

I'm trying to graph two seperate workbooks which contain information downloaded from two monitoring systems.  The two systems have been logging data over a 30-day period, but system 1 logs information every 5 minutes and system 2 logs every 15 minutes.

I started adding two blank lines the system 2 data to line up the times and data for both systems, but this became very tedious very quickly.

System 1 contains 8640 rows/records and system 2 contains 2880 rows/records, but as mentioned, both are logged over a 30-day period.  I now wish to graph both sets of data and have them matched up over the timeline.

Is there a quick or easy way to do this?

ps, I do realise I could change both systems to log at the same intervals, but this does not help with the data I already have!

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Plot one series (labels and values) first as an X Y (Scatter) to suit, then select the second series (labels and values), copy, click in plot area, Paste Special..., New series, Columns, Categories (X Values) in First Column and OK may suit.

Simplified example:
[image: SO21429094 example]